# how to fire function every time ngMessages finds an invalid field?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, ng-messages

I'm attempting to compile an array of front-end error objects for every time ngMessages catches a changed input field as invalid.

I'm used to the event-driven formvalidation.io library. Is there any event or function to listen for/adjust respectively in ngMessages?

I'm assuming there must be a function that says "Oh, we have an invalid field... do this now".  That's what I'm looking for.

If there is such a function, how would one get the field being validated?

Thanks, folks!

Comment: you can watch the form validation object...and any particular properties you want

Comment: @charlietfl could you maybe show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from @charlietfl is correct.

Thank you!

> you can watch the form validation object...and any particular
>   properties you want – charlietfl Jan 26 at 21:54